# Sort a 2D jagged list based on a custom row order using python 2

Tags: python, sorting

Suppose I have the following jagged list in python:

```
a = [[73, 74, 93, 97, 147],
     [5, 11, 12, 47],
     [987, 988, 989, 990, 991],
     [15, 16, 17, 22, 71, 988],
     [15, 16, 17]]
```

I also happen to have the following list:

```
b = [5, 3, 2, 4, 1]
```

I wish to sort the the rows of list `a` based on the sort order provided by `b`, i.e., after sort, `a` should be:

```
a = [[15, 16, 17],
     [987, 988, 989, 990, 991],
     [5, 11, 12, 47],
     [15, 16, 17, 22, 71, 988],
     [73, 74, 93, 97, 147]]
```

I do not understand how to do it. Please help me.

Comment: You can use `[a[i-1] for i in b]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
output = [a[j-1] for j in b]
```